# Why is Hapi.js POST handler returning an empty payload?

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I have a Hapi route that accepts a POST call, but the `request` returns a `null` value for the payload.

```
server.route({
    method: ['POST', 'PUT'],
    path: '/create_note',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        console.log(request.payload); // returns `null`
        return reply(request.payload);
    }
});
```

I'm using Postman to send a POST call to `http://localhost:8000/create_note?name=test`.

In the handler function, `console.log(request.payload)` returns `null`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `payload` is the request body, unless you're sending a request body through Postman, `null` is the expected value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing query string parameters with `?name=test`, not the POST request payload.

You can access the query parameters by referencing `request.query`.

An HTTP request to `http://localhost:8000/create_note?name=test` will yield:

```
console.log(request.query); // {name: 'test'}
```